# Is there a way to fire JQuery .when on the moment that one of a list of deferred functions finishes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I want to build a pseudo queue using ajax.
And then I want to fire five calls at a time.

The pseudo code would look something like:

```
For each item in list as ajaxN{
FuncToRun.push(ajaxN);
If(count(FuncToRun)==5){
    .when (FuncToRun).onefinishes{
        FuncToRun.pop(success Func)
    }
}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is requirement to fire _five callbacks_ "on the moment that one of a list of deferred functions finishes?" ? , or call five `deferred` functions, then fire _one callback_ "on the moment that one of a list of deferred functions finishes?" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds rather like you want [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/).

However, a Callbacks object doesn't offer a `length` property so you need to contrive some mechanism for monitoring the number of functions in the queue and for firing it when your threshold (5) is reached.

For example, you could wrap a Callbacks object in a little namespace with a handful of custom methods and properties.

```
var FunctionList = (function() {
    var list = $.Callbacks(),
        length = 0,
        threshold = 5;
    function add(fn) {
        if(fn  && $.isFunction(fn)) {
            list.add(fn);
            if(++length >= threshold) {
                list.fire().empty();
                length = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new TypeError("FunctionList.add() must be passed a function");
        }
    }
    function getLength(x) { return length; }
    function setThreshold(x) { threshold = x; }
    function getThreshold() { return threshold; }
    return {
        add: add,
        getLength: getLength,
        setThreshold: setThreshold,
        getThreshold: getThreshold
    };
})();
```

As written, `FunctionList` is very basic and meets the minimum requirements of the question. It could be taken much further to expose more of the Callbacks API (eg. flags, `.disable()`, `.fireWith()`, `.has()`, `.lock()`, `.remove()`).  You could also refactor the namespace as a constructor, allowing more than one `FunctionList` to be used simultaneously.

How you populate `FunctionList` is up to you. `FunctionList.add(...)` could certainly be called in response to AJAX success, which is what you appear to want.